# How to run python script with another file as input param to an azure Function?

Tags: python, c#, azure, function, azure-functions

My python script will accept a .rpt file and generate an HTML file as output.
For example on my windows command prompt, I use the following command to get the expected output file.

```
python script1.py input1.rpt
```

and this will produce output.htm file

Now how can I do the same from azure function? I tried with the steps from [doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob),and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-vs-code-serverless-python-02) and created an azure function, but I am not clear how to call my python script above and provide my rpt file as input to get the expected result. How can I execute the python file and produce the output HTML file without making any changes to the script1.py file. I can execute the above command from my windows command prompt and it is accepting the .rpt file and writes the output file to the same directory.
My expectation: How can execute the same from my azure function?(**with no changes to script1.py**)
I can keep the script1.py file in the base folder. I can upload the input.rpt file to blob storage to trigger the function. Any suggestions on how to call my script1.py from the azure functions init.py and get this trigged when the .rpt file is uploaded to Azure blob storage. ?

Comment: What is your function trigger? The link you shared is a basic http triggered function example where the function can triggered by http call where you can do POST request with data in the request body. In your case, you want to process a file, so instead blob trigger/binding or event grid trigger suites your need. You would need to understand how Function works first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ and

Answer (score 0):

**First, choose a trigger.**

For example, if you select httptrigger, you can put your logic in the body of the function like this:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    #
    #
    #Put your logic here.
    #
    #
    return func.HttpResponse(
        "This is a test.",
        status_code=200
    )
```

And you should write the required package in the requirements.txt.

This is the structure of the function app:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#folder-structure

Httptrigger needs you to hit the endpoint.

On local, after you start the function app, you will get the function url.

On azure, you can get the url in this place:

[image]

[image]

The above is a brief introduction to httptrigger. For other triggers, you only need to meet the trigger conditions to run, you only need to put the original Python script into the function body of the function.

**Second, you need to use input binding.**

Please refer to this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#supported-bindings

From your requirement, you can use blob input. this will help you achieve your goal:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=python